# Two date timestamp in one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have table product :

```
 - id : int;
 - name : varchar(100);
 - date_operation : timestamp 
 - date_confirmation : timestamp
```

but I'm not allowed to add two dates timestamp in phpmyadmin

Comment: First you should know why and where timestamp is used

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date_operation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default ’0000-00-00 00:00:00′,
date_confirmation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

As @Umair Khan commented you should know why and where timestamp is used and useful.